# Views Module-Content Images Center?

Tags: views, 7, media

How would I center a Content-Image with the Views Module? I would edit the css, however each image is a different width/height. See image: [image: Drupal Views Module:Image no centered]

How would I center each images to the text in the Drupal Views module?

Comment: You should use _image style_ to make same height and width of each image.

Comment: That has nothing to do with centering the images.

Comment: As you mentioned _each image is a different width/height_, so I suggest you to use _image style_ so each image has same height and width. You can only center image using _CSS_ and CSS question is off topic here.